# How to detect if a class property is private or protected

Tags: php, oop

How can I detect if a class property is private or protected **without** using external libraries (pure PHP only)? How can I check if I can set the property from outside the class or I cannot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if an object property is private in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821927/detect-if-an-object-property-is-private-in-php)

Comment: See this post mate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821927/detect-if-an-object-property-is-private-in-php

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @middus To see if I can set them outside the class.

Comment: I understood that. But why do you need to find this out? Most reasons I can think of are symptoms of a bad architecture.

Comment: @middus An user class is called and it should contains some object property of other classes. I have to set them. I could make the user extends a parent class where these variables are loaded with __construct() and accessible. Or I can set them outside without any parent class. The only difference is that if the user will set his own __construct() he will have to include every time parent::__construct() with the latter option.

Comment: @middus how would you manage this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Reflection` classes.

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.isprivate.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.isprotected.php

Answer (score 8):

Use [Reflection.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

```
<?php
    class Test {
        private $foo;
        public $bar;
    }

    $reflector = new ReflectionClass(get_class(new Test()));

    $prop = $reflector->getProperty('foo');
    var_dump($prop->isPrivate());

    $prop = $reflector->getProperty('bar');
    var_dump($prop->isPrivate());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`print_r($object_or_class_name);`

It should draw it out for you, properties that you can or can't access..

For example:

```
class tempclass {
    private $priv1 = 1;
    protected $prot1 = 2;
    public $pub1 = 3;

}
$tmp = new tempclass();
print_r($tmp);
exit;
```

Just to illustrate that I have one private property, one protected property, and one public property. Then we see the output of `print_r($tmp);`:

```
tempclass Object
(
    [priv1:tempclass:private] => 1
    [prot1:protected] => 2
    [pub1] => 3
)
```

Or am I misunderstanding your post? Haha

Comment: I think the OP wants to be able to detect programatically whether a property is private or public. If he just wanted to know he could open up the file.

Comment: Oh my bad. Once he accepts an answer pointing to reflection, I'll delete my post to avoid confusing others :D

Comment: Don't have to. Just because it's not the most useful answer, doesn't make it completely useless. Someone else might google upon it and actually just need a print_r visualization of the issue.

Comment: I see.. Alright, thanks @mario, I'll keep this post.. Sorry for any trouble caused